# ruby `rescue in block in connect': Failed to open TCP connection to api

Tags: ruby, api

I am fairly new to ruby and I am having issues using code that I found on this 
[github](https://github.com/jsgoecke/whitepages). It is meant to use the Whitepages API to use their service and I am using it to do a reverse phone lookup. Here is my whitepages.rb file:

```
require 'json'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'


class Whitepages

#Initialize the Whitepages class
# * api_key - The API key obtained from the Whitpages Developer website
def initialize(api_key)
  api_version = "1.0"

  @api_key = api_key
  @base_uri = "http://api.whitepages.com/"
  @find_person_uri = @base_uri + "find_person/" + api_version + "/?"
  @reverse_phone_uri = @base_uri + "reverse_phone/" + api_version + "/?"
  @reverse_address_uri = @base_uri + "reverse_address/" + api_version + "/?"

  @uri = URI.parse(@base_uri)
  @http = Net::HTTP.new(@uri.host, @uri.port)
end

#Retrieves contact information about a telephone number
#Accepts a hash:
# * phone - May be 7 digits if state provided otherwise 10 (*REQUIRED*)
# * state - Two digit code for the state
#More details may be found here: http://developer.whitepages.com/docs/Methods/reverse_phone
def reverse_phone(options)  
  resp, data = @http.get(build_uri(options, "reverse_phone"))

  if resp.code== 200
    return JSON.parse(data)
  else
    raise Exception,"code",resp.code
  end

end



#Build the appropriate URL
def build_uri(options, type)
  case type
  when "reverse_phone"
    built_uri = @reverse_phone_uri
  when "reverse_address"
    built_uri = @reverse_address_uri
  when "find_person"
    built_uri = @find_person_uri
  end

  options.each do |key,value|
    if value != nil
      built_uri = built_uri + key + "=" + value.gsub(' ', '%20') + ";"
    end
  end

  built_uri = built_uri + "api_key=" + @api_key + ";outputtype=JSON"
  return built_uri
end

end
```

And here is the class I use to test the code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require './whitepages'

API_KEY = MY ACTUAL API KEY AS A STRING

wp = Whitepages.new(API_KEY)



data = wp.reverse_phone({ "phone"   => "4155551212", 
                      "state"   => "CA" })
```

When I run this file, I get the error: `rescue in block in connect': Failed to open TCP connection to api.whitepages.com:80 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known) (SocketError)`

I can't find anything online specifically about connecting to APIs that would help me. Please, any help is greatly appreciated. PS: If you need to test the code, it does not take long at all to get a free API key from whitepages.com

Comment: Most recent commit on that repo was four years ago, and a cursory Google search yields [this information](https://pro.whitepages.com/developer/documentation/api-overview/), which would seem to indicate that your target URL should be `proapi.whitepages.com:80`. It's possible that github repo is outdated.

Comment: using `proagpi.whitepages.com` in the browser seems to show that it is no longer accessible..any help on how i can get this to work would be great